# How to use tab navigation to control the pdf viewer in IE11

Tags: accessibility, internet-explorer-11, pdf-viewer

We are trying to improve handicapped accessibility of one of our pages and allow a user to perform all the actions without a mouse. The page contains some buttons and an iframe with a pdf document. In IE11 I can tab through the buttons but when the control goes to the pdf viewer iframe, nothing is highlighted and pressing tab doesn't do anything.

In chrome pressing tab will cycle in through the buttons, than the handful of controls on the pdf and than step out of the viewer and start to cycle again. How do I get IE to do the same thing.

As a side note if I use shift+tab to cycle backwards, IE will ignore the iframe and cycle through the elements correctly. In fact after tabbing into the iframe, I can use shift+tab to get back to the button controls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is your page designed? Could you provide a sample code that could describe your issue and requirement directly?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to test PDF accessibility in the browser, which isn't really how things are done. The PDF viewers in web browsers are inferior to Acrobat, and people who need assistive technology likely won't be using the PDF readers built into IE or Chrome anyway.

As a starting point, I'd recommend opening up the document in Acrobat and making sure that it has tags. If it doesn't, you can try to have Acrobat generate them for you. If you're using any kind of a complex layout (other than simple text, images, and maybe lists), then the tagging will probably require you to manually review and correct them. PDF tags are structured very similar to HTML (but not entirely identical). If you already know HTML, then you'll probably be able to tag PDFs well enough. Otherwise, there's going to be a learning curve.

PDF remediation is an art unto itself that takes some time to master.

Here are some resources that will hopefully point you in the right direction:

- https://webaim.org/techniques/acrobat/
- https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/create-verify-pdf-accessibility.html
- https://www.washington.edu/accessibility/documents/pdf-acrobat/

Comment: The pdf is generated by us and presented in an iframe. This is old functionality and we would very much prefer not to have to download the pdf. The pdf is not modifiable or interactive in any way. Chrome presents an ability to zoom and scroll and that's it. IE (with the use of mouse) allows to scroll. This is all the functionality that we really need.

Comment: @Eugene -- For a PDF to be accessible, it needs to be tagged correctly. The order of the tags also sets reading order and tab order. It sounds like what you're trying to do here is an uncommon implementation.